# how to add dark mode with local storage in react

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, darkmode

```
function Theme() {
  
  const toggleMode = (mode) => {
    if (mode === "add") {
      document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
    }
  };
  const mode = localStorage.getItem("mode");
  return (
    <div className="theme_toggle">
        <div className="day_mode flex items-center" onClick={() => toggleMode("add")} >
          <Image src="/dark.svg" width="20" height="20" alt="night_mood" />
        </div>
        <div className="night_mode flex items-center" onClick={() => toggleMode("remove")} >
          <Image src="/day_white.svg" width="20" height="20" alt="day_mood" />
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Theme
```

I'm attempting to add a dark mode, and I've added it successfully. I want it to be saved after a refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply save and  get it from localStorage and apply it to document  in useEffect

sth like this :

```
function Theme() {


  useEffect(()=>{
    const mode = localStorage.getItem("mode");
  
  
     if(mode){
       document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
    
     }

   },[])
  
  const toggleMode = (mode) => {
    if (mode === "add") {
      document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
      localStorage.setItem('mode','dark')
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
      localStorage.removeItem('mode')
      
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="theme_toggle">
      <div className="day_mode flex items-center" onClick={() => toggleMode("add")} >
        <Image src="/dark.svg" width="20" height="20" alt="night_mood" />
      </div>
      <div className="night_mode flex items-center" onClick={() => toggleMode("remove")} >
        <Image src="/day_white.svg" width="20" height="20" alt="day_mood" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Theme
```

Comment: ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

Comment: aha you are using nextjs, let me update my answer

Comment: happy to hear that, if it's what you were looking for, please mark it as the answer and vote up